Building with Fyne - cannot find -lopengl32: No such file or directory
I'm trying to set up an application using Fyne, starting with just the basic template it gives. However, when building the application I get this message, and nothing runs:
PS C:\Users\kmall\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\acme-vdb> go run main.go
# command-line-arguments
C:\Program Files (x86)\Go\pkg\tool\windows_386\link.exe: running gcc failed: exit status 1
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../libgdi32.a when searching for -lgdi32
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../..\libgdi32.a when searching for -lgdi32
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../libgdi32.a when searching for -lgdi32
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgdi32: No such file or directory
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../libgdi32.a when searching for -lgdi32
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../libopengl32.a when searching for -lopengl32
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../..\libopengl32.a when searching for -lopengl32
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../libopengl32.a when searching for -lopengl32
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lopengl32: No such file or directory
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../libopengl32.a when searching for -lopengl32
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../libopengl32.a when searching for -lopengl32
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../..\libopengl32.a when searching for -lopengl32
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../libopengl32.a when searching for a when searching for -lopengl32
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lopengl32: No such file or directory
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../libopengl32.a when searching for -lopengl32
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../libopengl32.a when searching for -lopengl32
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../..\libopengl32.a when searching for -lopengl32
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../libopengl32.a when searching for -lopengl32
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lopengl32: No such file or directory
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../libopengl32.a when searching for -lopengl32
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Here is the code from the basic template Fyne gives you:
package main

import (
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/container"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget"
)

func main() {
    a := app.New()
    w := a.NewWindow("Hello")

    hello := widget.NewLabel("Hello Fyne!")
    w.SetContent(container.NewVBox(
        hello,
        widget.NewButton("Hi!", func() {
            hello.SetText("Welcome :)")
        }),
    ))

    w.ShowAndRun()
}

I have tried running go mod tidy, go clean -modcache, and updated graphics drivers already with no change, and can't find any other solutions to similar problems online.
Ideally, it should compile and render a window that looks like this:
people also asked for go env output and gcc version:
gcc version 14.1.0
set GO111MODULE=on
set GOARCH=386
set GOBIN=
set GOCACHE=C:\Users\kmall\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOENV=C:\Users\kmall\AppData\Roaming\go\env
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOEXPERIMENT=
set GOFLAGS=
set GOHOSTARCH=386
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOINSECURE=
set GOMODCACHE=C:\Users\kmall\go\pkg\mod
set GONOPROXY=
set GONOSUMDB=
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\Users\kmall\go
set GOPRIVATE=
set GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org,direct
set GOROOT=C:\Program Files (x86)\Go
set GOSUMDB=sum.golang.org
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLCHAIN=auto
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Go\pkg\tool\windows_386
set GOVCS=
set GOVERSION=go1.22.4
set GCCGO=gccgo
set GO386=sse2
set AR=ar
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set GOMOD=C:\Users\kmall\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\acme-vdb\go.mod
set GOWORK=
set CGO_CFLAGS=-O2 -g
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-O2 -g
set CGO_FFLAGS=-O2 -g
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-O2 -g
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m32 -mthreads -Wl,--no-gc-sections -fmessage-length=0 -ffile-prefix-map=C:\Users\kmall\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build1144242527=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches


Did you following the Windows Guide? https://docs.fyne.io/started/

Yes, followed to the tee and the checker application doesn't give me any issues

Is your go and mingw both 64bit

Looks like your go and mingw is incompatible as in the error is noticable

Show go env Output and gcc -v

edited the post to include those

Your go is 32bit, your GOARCH should be amd64

Go and mingw is incompatible because Go installion is 32Bit and mingw is 64Bit.
Install golang 64Bit Version

It does look like Go is running a 32bit compiler but that could be a red herring.
The docs can’t have been followed exactly as they are for setting up the MSYS2 terminal and environment (64bit). I would check to see if the build works there before trying other configurations.
